# Laravel Mail - set a different Sender address to from address

Tags: laravel, email

I want to be able to set a different 'Sender' to the 'From address' in Laravel emails. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 9+, you can configure the sender of the email in **two ways**:

1. Using the Envelope: You can specify the "from" address and "replyTo"
   address by returning a new
   `Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope` instance from the `envelope()`
   method in your `Mailable` class.

```php
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;

public function envelope(): Envelope
{
    return new Envelope(
        from: new Address('johndoe@example.com', 'John Doe'),
        replyTo: [
            new Address('jennydoe@example.com', 'Jenny Doe'),
        ],
        subject: 'Order Created',
    );
}
```

2. Using a Global "from" address: If your application uses the same
   "from" address for all of its emails, you can define a global "from"
   address in your `config/mail.php` configuration file. This address
   will be used if no other "from" address is specified within the
   `Mailable` class.

```php
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

In addition, you may define a global "reply_to" address within your `config/mail.php` configuration file:

'reply_to' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

If you are using a version of Laravel 8 or lower it is otherwise, in the `Mailable` class you can do it like this

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('johndoe@example.com')
                ->sender('jennydoe@example.com', 'Jenny')
                ->view('emails.order-created');
}
```

You can also use the global option of the configuration file in previous versions of Laravel 9.

You can get more information in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#configuring-the-sender).

Answer (score 1):

Edit config/mail.php:
and set the from like this:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'xelber@example.org', 'name' => 'Xelber Stackoverflow']
```